# What is the difference between surrounding the type with square brackets and surrounding the whole object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

What is the difference between this code:

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    phoneNumber: { type: Number, required: false, unique: true },
    address: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectID, required: true, ref: "Address" }],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

And this code:

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    phoneNumber: { type: Number, required: false, unique: true },
    address: { type: [mongoose.Types.ObjectID], required: true, ref: "Address" },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

**NOTICE:**

- In the first code, I surrounded the whole `address` object with square brackets.
- In the second code, I only surrounded the `type` property of the `address` with square brackets.

What I want to know is how that will impact the app's behavior.
Is there any difference?

Thanks.

Comment: One is an object, the other an object array with one item. What is the aim here?

Comment: In the first Schema you have an array of addresses. In the second Schema there's only one address with an array of types (which makes no sense)

Comment: @mplungjan I was just trying to understand the difference between the two approaches, but I have an answer now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both declare an array-of-references, but there are some subtle differences.

Let's take this simple schema:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  address: { type: [ String ], required: true, default: undefined }
});
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

This will apply the options (`required` and `default`) to the `address` array-of-strings *as a whole*:

```
// This will fail validation:
//   ValidatorError: Path `address` is required
const doc = new User({});

// This will pass validation:
const doc = new User({ address : [] });
```

Now change the position of the brackets in the schema:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  address: [{ type: String, required: true, default: undefined }]
});
```

This will apply the options to the *elements* of the `address` array:

```
// This will pass validation, `address` itself isn't required:
const user = new User({});
// This will also pass validation, for the same reason:
const user = new User({ address : [] });
// This will fail validation, because elements of the array are required to have a proper value
// ValidatorError: Path `address.0` is required
const user = new User({ address : [ '' ] });
```

**EDIT**: if you want to enforce that the `address` field is always defined *and* has at least one element, you have to use a custom validator. For your schema, it would look like this:

```
address: { 
  type:     [ mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID ],
  ref:      'Address',
  required: true,
  default:  undefined,
  validate: a => Array.isArray(a) && a.length > 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what if I want to make the address required as well as the elements of the array, how can I achieve that?

Comment: @BakriAlkhateeb see edit.